# SOLR: Simultaneous search in different languages

Tags: search, solr, multicore, multilingual

I have a Solr instance that gets and indexes data about companies from DB. A DB data about a single company can be provided in several languages(english and russian for example).All the companies, of course, have a unikue key that is a uniqueKey in solr index too. I need to present solr search in all the languages at once.

How can it be performed?
1. Multicore? I've build two seperate cores with each language data, but i can't search in two indexes simultaneously.

```
localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr/core0/,localhost:8983/solr/core1/&indent=true&q=*:*&distributed=true
```

or

```
localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?shards=localhost:8983/solr/core0/,localhost:8983/solr/core1/&indent=true&id:123456
```

gives no results. while searching in each core is succesful.

1. Enable Name field(for example) as a multivalued is not a solution, because a different language data data from DB are get by different procedures. And the value is just rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the multicore piece, but have you considered creating two fields in a single core - one for each language?  You could then combine with an "OR" which is the default, so a query for:

```
en:"query test here" OR ru:"query test here"
```

would be an example

Comment: but how to get that data into the index then? because I hava two different procedures for retrieving data from the DB...

Comment: they are stored procedures and retrieve all the data as one result set.

Comment: Yes that's challenging.  One idea is to store the values of all the fields you need, retrieve them when indexing, merging your new values with the stored ones, and re-inserting both.

Comment: Do you know the input language? Then you are lucky. If you don't want to have to know it: add all the language fields to one schema and to your dismax configurations. SOLR will handle the input for each language field according to its query chain without you having to worry about it. The more effort you put into the import process the less won't get in your way when querying. You want to end up with a query like: /solr/dismax?q="any language input" and with this approach you can.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are possibly using the DataImportHandler to load your data. You can implement @Mike Sokolov's answer or implement the multivalued solution via the use of a Solr client. You would need to write some custom code in a client like [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) (or one of the other clients listed on [IntegratingSolr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr) in the Solr Wiki) to pull both languages in separate queries from your database and then parse the data from both results into a common data/result set that can be transformed into a single Solr document.